# how to stop setInterval called from function by using clearInterval called in other function

Tags: jquery

Hi guys how i can stop `setInterval` called from function by using `clearInterval` called in other function?

It's necessary to use `setInterval` in function because i use same function to close my popup window by click x and i want to stop timer by closing pop up window.

JS:

```
function onlinechat(id) {
        $.ajax({
            ....
            success: function(data){
                $(".myclass").append(data);
                var stopChat = window.setInterval(function() {
                    loadmore(id);
                }, 2500);
            }
        });     
    return false;
}

function loadmore(id){
    .....
}

function close_online_chat(){
    $('.lobibox-window').hide();
    clearInterval(stopChat);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="lobibox-window">
    <div class="lobibox-header">
        <span class="btn-close" onclick="close_online_chat();return false;">×</span>
    </div>
    <div class="lobibox-body" style="height: 510px;">
        <div class="myclass"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the variable as a global variable first.

```
var stopChat; //define as global variable
function onlinechat(id) {
        $.ajax({
            ....
            success: function(data){
                $(".myclass").append(data);
                //don't use var here
                stopChat = window.setInterval(function() {
                    loadmore(id);
                }, 2500);
            }
        });     
    return false;
}

function loadmore(id){
    .....
}

function close_online_chat(){
    $('.lobibox-window').hide();
    clearInterval(stopChat);
}
```